# How to get all "harbours" (nodes and polygon) out of osm.pbf

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, osmconvert

I downloaded the germany.osm.pbf from geofabrik and would like to extract all the harbours. I did that already for points by using ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" -where "harbour IN ('yes','1','true')" Harbours.gpkg germany-latest.osm.pbf points
```

But unfortunately a lot harbours exist just as polygons. How to get the polygon harbours as points?

Comment: Either display the polygons as points, or convert them.

Comment: Please try this untested command `ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" -dialect SQLite -sql "select ST_Centroid(geometry) as geometry from multipolygons where harbour IN ('yes','1','true') LIMIT 10" Harbours.gpkg germany-latest.osm.pbf`. If it works add more attributes into select and remove limit. If you want to append to existing point layer some more switches are needed `-append -update -nln points` (untested as well).

Comment: That's my solution! You can turn that comment into a answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it. My assumption is that the polygon layers contain only harbour areas *(if not you will have to filter the polygon layer to extract all the harbours from it. To filter out harbours you can check from other_tags column and maybe landuse using the **harbour attribute identifier**)*.

Convert the Harbour polygon layer from polygon to points using QGIS Polygon centroid tool. Navigvate from the menu
**Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Centroids**  (**Polygon Centroid**, depending on your qgis version).

[image]

After the conversion merge the new centroid layer and points layer. Though the columns in each layer is different the merged layer should contain all the columns from the two layers

**Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Merge Vector** .  Select the layers and other settings as required and click Run. Once complete the resulting layer would have all the points together.
[image]